# inflate another layout below in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-inflate

this is my post shape xml fiile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/hiddenLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_page_pic"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/pageNameTV"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdasdsd"
        android:id="@+id/postTimeTV"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/normal_end"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pageNameTV"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pageNameTV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my feed fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="23dp"
    android:paddingRight="13dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/feeds_container">

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

my code is

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

        RelativeLayout hiddenLayout = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);

        RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.feeds_container);
        View hiddenInfo = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_shape, myLayout, false);
        myLayout.addView(hiddenInfo);

        hiddenInfo = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_shape, myLayout, false);
        myLayout.addView(hiddenInfo);

        return mRootView;
    }
```

what I trying to do is get copy of post_shape.xml into feed_fragment.xml the first one is right but when I'm trying to add another one below the first one I got this http://s14.postimg.org/p8sh0yiq9/ant.jpg
I'm really for my bad English and and I hope u will understand my problem if you see the picture

Comment: use linearlayout instead of relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got 2 chocies here...
1.Replace RealtiveLayout with LinearLayout in file Feed Fragment (LinearLayout must take the whole screen too so it will insert them one under the other)
2.instand of ScrollView and RelativeLayout use ListView and Adapter which is much useful here.

[ListView Example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)